# How to identify the element name in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

The element to match is as follows:

```
... some html....

<table>
some <tr's>
<tr><td>"caption in a <a> tag"</td><td> result value here </td></tr>
more <tr's>

.... more html
```

I'm using Selenium IDE but don't see a way to match/capture the result value text anywhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```
<yyy name="iggy" caption="abcd" level="20"></yyy>
```

you would want to use

```
assertAttribute("iggy@caption", "abcd")
```

This uses the name as a locator and @caption to specify the attribute you want. You could follow it with

```
assertAttribute("iggy@level", "20")
```

to check the level attribute. You might use 'validateAttribute' instead of 'assertAttribute'. If you want to capture the attribute value use 'storeAttribute'.